# Control 'c1_t1' of type TextBox must be placed inside a form tag with runat=server in Asp.Net

Tags: asp.net

I am creating shopping website so on admin side i am adding add_product.aspx web form but i am getting this error "Control 'c1_t1' of type 'TextBox' must be placed inside a form tag with runat=server." product page html is given below and it also have master page..

```
    <%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/admin/admin.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="add_product.aspx.cs" Inherits="admin_add_product" %>


        <asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="c1" Runat="Server">
            <h3>Add Product Page</h3>

            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>Product Name</td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="t1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                    </td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td>Product Description</td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="t2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                    </td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td>Product Price</td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="t3" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                    </td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td>Product Qty</td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="t4" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                    </td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td>Product Image</td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUploadImageUploader" runat="server" />
                    </td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2">
                        <asp:Button ID="btnUpload" runat="server" Text="Upload" OnClick="btnUpload_Click" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </asp:Content>
```

it also have Master Page and i am adding master page code below

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="admin.master.cs" Inherits="admin_admin" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Simple Responsive Admin</title>
    <!-- BOOTSTRAP STYLES-->
    <link href="assets/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <!-- FONTAWESOME STYLES-->
    <link href="assets/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <!-- CUSTOM STYLES-->
    <link href="assets/css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <!-- GOOGLE FONTS-->
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
</head>
<body>
    <form>
        <div id="wrapper">
            <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
                <div class="adjust-nav">
                    <div class="navbar-header">
                        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".sidebar-collapse">
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        </button>
                        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
                            <img src="assets/img/logo.png" />

                        </a>

                    </div>

                    <span class="logout-spn">
                        <a href="#" style="color: #fff;">LOGOUT</a>

                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- /. NAV TOP  -->
            <nav class="navbar-default navbar-side" role="navigation">
                <div class="sidebar-collapse">
                    <ul class="nav" id="main-menu">



                        <li class="active-link">
                            <a href="index.html"><i class="fa fa-desktop "></i>Dashboard <span class="badge">Included</span></a>
                        </li>


                        <li>
                            <a href="ui.html"><i class="fa fa-table "></i>UI Elements  <span class="badge">Included</span></a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="blank.html"><i class="fa fa-edit "></i>Blank Page  <span class="badge">Included</span></a>
                        </li>


                        <li>
                            <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-qrcode "></i>My Link One</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-bar-chart-o"></i>My Link Two</a>
                        </li>

                        <li>
                            <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-edit "></i>My Link Three </a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-table "></i>My Link Four</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-edit "></i>My Link Five </a>
                        </li>

                    </ul>
                </div>

            </nav>
            <!-- /. NAV SIDE  -->
            <div id="page-wrapper">
                <div id="page-inner">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-12">
                            <h2>ADMIN DASHBOARD</h2>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- /. ROW  -->
                    <hr />

                    <!-- /. ROW  -->
                    <!--This is content area -->
                    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="c1" runat="server">

                    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>

                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- /. ROW  -->
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12 ">
                    <br />
                    <div class="alert alert-danger">
                        <strong>Want More Icons Free ? </strong>Checkout fontawesome website and use any icon <a target="_blank" href="http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icons/">Click Here</a>.
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- /. ROW  -->
        </div>

    <div class="footer">


        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                &copy;  2014 yourdomain.com | Design by: <a href="http://binarytheme.com" style="color: #fff;" target="_blank">www.binarytheme.com</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


        <!-- /. WRAPPER  -->
        <!-- SCRIPTS -AT THE BOTOM TO REDUCE THE LOAD TIME-->
        <!-- JQUERY SCRIPTS -->
        <script src="assets/js/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
        <!-- BOOTSTRAP SCRIPTS -->
        <script src="assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <!-- CUSTOM SCRIPTS -->
        <script src="assets/js/custom.js"></script>

    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Does the master page have a form?  The error is pretty clear about needing one, where's the form?

Comment: As the error message says, you don't have a form-element with runat="server" here nor the master page I presume.

Comment: sry sir but now i added master page code

Comment: master page have form tag sir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error states:

> "Control 'c1_t1' of type 'TextBox' must be placed inside a form tag with runat=server."

And your form element is:

```
<form>
```

The error is telling you want to do.  The form element needs `runat="server"`:

```
<form runat="server">
```

Comment: i added form tag before table it gives warning "Element form must not be nested with in element 'form' "

Comment: @Rakesh: Did you nest a form element inside of another form element.  Because, again, that message is clearly telling you not to do that.  Have you tried reading any of these error messages that you get?

Comment: i read warning but i dint nested any form tag inside another form tag look at the above code there is no another form tag

Comment: @Rakesh: Ok, then what's the problem?  The error in the question states that you need `runat="server"` on your form, so put `runat="server"` on your form.  What isn't working at that point?

Comment: yeah ryt problem was occuring bczz there was no run at server in form tag on master page